# Positional argument required PyPDF2

Tags: python-3.x, parameter-passing, pypdf

I am trying to split PDF file by pages before converting it to Txt.
I am using this code to split it but is got and error related to the positional argument. I assume it should be the first page of the list, but I can't find the way to pass it into the code itself.
This the code:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

pdf_document = "5Dec2019.pdf"
pdf = PdfFileReader(pdf_document)

for page in range(pdf.getNumPages()):
    pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter
    current_page = pdf.getPage(page)
    pdf_writer.addPage(current_page)

    outputFilename = "example-page-{}.pdf".format(page + 1)
    with open(outputFilename, "rb") as out:
        pdf_writer.write(out)

        print("created", outputFilename)
```

This is the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-ab33e5847c35> in <module>
      7     pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter
      8     current_page = pdf.getPage(page)
----> 9     pdf_writer.addPage(current_page)
     10 
     11     outputFilename = "example-page-{}.pdf".format(page + 1)

TypeError: addPage() missing 1 required positional argument: 'page'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're assigning `pdf_writer` to the class `PdfFileWriter`, and not an *instance* of that class.

The remedy is simple:

```
    pdf_writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
    # you need these parens/brackets ^^
```

Also: when you're opening your output file you're using `'rb'` instead of what it should be: `'wb'`.

Comment: It worked, sorry for the silly question. I have now another issue with the code in that it won't create the outputFilename variable. It gives me this type of error  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'example-page-1.pdf'

Comment: Ah, change `'rb'` to `'wb'` in your `with` statement.